# SVG textpath doesn't render foreign languages correctly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, multilingual

In the following fiddle I am trying to render Hindi in a textpath, however, characters do not cluster as expected. I should see नमस्ते, but instead I see न म स ् त े. If I take it out of the textpath and just wrap it in a text the issue is fixed however I need the text on a path.

It works on Firefox, but it is broken for [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), Safari, and Chrome, suggesting a WebKit issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/xt1o6kg9/

```html
<textPath href="#path">
  नमस्ते
</textPath>
```

If this issue can't be fixed, where can I file this issue with the appropriate moderators of WebKit (or whoever)?

Comment: Chrome: https://www.chromium.org/issue-tracking Safari: https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: Opera and Chrome are no longer webkit, they are chromium.

Comment: You may try to use unicode. For example for ई you may try to use `&#x908;` This is the [Unicode Block “Devanagari”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0900) where you can search the chars you need

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that unicode would be converted before the renderer gets it so that wouldn't be effective.

Comment: Yes converting to unicode first does not fix the problem. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Sounds like https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374526

Comment: Is there any solution yet? I am still running into the same problem